# Switch between Python 3.5 and 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I had the latest **Python 3.6** installed on my machine but to download tensor flow, I also installed the 3.5 version on the same machine. When checking the python version on cmd prompt, it is showing me 3.6.3.

> C:\Users\aakash.sharma01>py Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default,
>   Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

How do I change the default version to 3.5?

Also, when I check the installation path for Anaconda it shows me the python36 dll's. Path:

```
(C:\Users\aakash.sharma01\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3)
```

Not sure if it has anything to do with this issue?

Comment: You can create a new conda environment with Python 3.5, see [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: "*to download tensor flow, I also installed the 3.5 version*" Why?! TensorFlow has supported Python 3.6 since version 1.2. Current version is 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install tensorflow with `conda` for Python 3.6:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Currently, this will give you version 1.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Other than using anaconda, other methods are also recommended.

If your OS is Ubuntu using `update-alternatives`.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --list python3
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python

>> Add python version

$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.4 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.4 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in auto mode
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.5 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in auto mode

>> Config python version

$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.4   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.5   2         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Then you can choose between two versions of python.

Answer (score 1):

To change the default python interpreter for anaconda use `conda install python=3.5`